A script using the requests module produces a 428 status code
I've created a script to issue a POST HTTP request with appropriate parameters, generated upon complying with the fields shown in this image, to this website. The script is supposed to produce a 200 status code, indicating that the response I received from the server was successful.
However, when I run the script, I always get a 428 status code in the second request. How can I fix the issue? Here is the script for your consideration:
import requests

url = 'https://wizzair.com/en-gb'
link = 'https://be.wizzair.com/24.9.0/Api/search/search'

payload = {"isFlightChange":False,"flightList":[{"departureStation":"TIA","arrivalStation":"VIE","departureDate":"2024-09-17"},{"departureStation":"VIE","arrivalStation":"TIA","departureDate":"2024-10-20"}],"adultCount":1,"childCount":0,"infantCount":0,"wdc":True}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Host': 'wizzair.com',
    'Referer': 'https://wizzair.com/en-gb',
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers.update(headers)
    r = session.get(url)
    print(r.status_code)
    session.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
    session.headers['Referer'] = 'https://wizzair.com/en-gb/booking/select-flight/TIA/VIE/2024-09-17/2024-10-20/1/0/0/null'
    session.headers['Host'] = 'be.wizzair.com'
    session.headers['Origin'] = 'https://wizzair.com'
    resp = session.post(link,json=payload)
    print(resp.status_code)


428 Precondition required indicates that there's something, probably a specific header, missing from your request. The documentation for the API you're using should tell you what.

You have tagged "web-scraping" but there is no web-scraping here. If you want to do this with web-scraping you just need to GET the URL that you're using as the Referer then analyse the response

This simply won't work.
Why? Because Wizzair protects their sites with an anti-bot solution from kasada.io.
If you inspect the headers of the request (in a browser) you'll notice the following:
access-control-allow-headers: x-kpsdk-ct, x-kpsdk-cd, x-kpsdk-h, x-kpdk-fc, x-kpsdk-v, x-kpsdk-r just to name a few there.
Also, there's another header key - x-kpsdk-ct.

The Kasada blocking errors are usually associated with some custom headers used by Kasada, such as the X-Kpsdk-Ct header

quote source
To bypass it, you'd have to hit the nail on the head of that request, if I can say so, keeping in mind that:

your headers must be spot on
you'd probably need to rotate your IP
there are cookies to go through and get, if you want to appear as a normal user
you'd have to change your scraping behavior because that gets analyzed too
you might have to deal with JavaScript fingerprinting

So, you can either do some trial and error and hope for the best or use an automated browser.
Alternatively, you could use a service that offers Web Scraping APIs, but that's paid.
On the final note, what you're trying to do is against their ToS.

The 428 HTTP status code indicates "Precondition Required," which means that the server requires certain conditions to be met before it can process the request.

Ensure All Required Headers Are Included
session.headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
session.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'

Check for Cookies


Since you’re using a Session, it should automatically handle cookies. However, check if the GET request sets any cookies that are relevant to the POST request
print(session.cookies.get_dict())

May this work:
import requests
url = 'https://wizzair.com/en-gb'
link = 'https://be.wizzair.com/24.9.0/Api/search/search'
payload = {
"isFlightChange": False,
"flightList": [
{"departureStation": "TIA", "arrivalStation": "VIE", "departureDate": "2024-09-17"},
{"departureStation": "VIE", "arrivalStation": "TIA", "departureDate": "2024-10-20"}
],
"adultCount": 1,
"childCount": 0,
"infantCount": 0,
"wdc": True
}
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'Host': 'wizzair.com',
'Referer': 'https://wizzair.com/en-gb',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
'Origin': 'https://wizzair.com',
}
with requests.Session() as session:
session.headers.update(headers)
# First, get the initial page to start a session and collect cookies
r = session.get(url)
print('GET status code:', r.status_code)
print('Cookies after GET:', session.cookies.get_dict())

# Update headers and send POST request
session.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
session.headers['Referer'] = 'https://wizzair.com/en-gb/booking/select-flight/TIA/VIE/2024-09-17/2024-10-20/1/0/0/null'
session.headers['Host'] = 'be.wizzair.com'

# Now, post to the search API
resp = session.post(link, json=payload)
print('POST status code:', resp.status_code)
print('Response:', resp.text)

